# Attempting to select multiple counts in a single query in MySQL

Tags: sql, database, select, count, nested

I have a table of shop orders. These orders have a boolean attribute that states whether they need to be delivered to the customer or not not. There is another table that states whether the order is complete or not.

I wanted to count the number of delivered invoices, remaining invoices and then just the total number of invoices that are completed(paid for).

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(SELECT INVOICE_ID FROM INVOICE_LINE AS I, INVOICE_COMPLETE AS IC WHERE TO_DELIVER = 1 AND I.INVOICE_ID = IC.INVOICE_ID AND IC.COMPLETE = 1) AS DELIVERED, 
    COUNT(SELECT INVOICE_ID FROM INVOICE_LINE AS I, INVOICE_COMPLETE AS IC WHERE TO_DELIVER = 0 AND I.INVOICE_ID = IC.INVOICE_ID AND IC.COMPLETE = 1) AS REMAINING,
    COUNT(INVOICE_ID) AS TOTAL
FROM INVOICE_LINE AS I, INVOICE_COMPLETE AS IC
WHERE TO_DELIVER = 1
AND I.INVOICE_ID = IC.INVOICE_ID
```

which is throwing the following syntax error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT INVOICE_ID FROM INVOICE_LINE AS I, INVOICE_COMPLETE AS IC WHERE TO_DELIVE' at line 2
```

Where am I going wrong here. This is my first time attempting to nest statements like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way: Outer join invoice_complete and count matches:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(IC.INVOICE_ID) AS DELIVERED, 
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(IC.INVOICE_ID) AS REMAINING,
  COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM INVOICE_LINE AS I
LEFT JOIN INVOICE_COMPLETE AS IC ON I.INVOICE_ID = IC.INVOICE_ID AND IC.COMPLETE = 1
WHERE TO_DELIVER = 1;
```

EDIT: Well, I should explain also what you did wrong: Count needs *, a column or an expression. For a column or an expression it would count non-null occurences, for * it counts records. You *can* use a select statement as an expression, but then it must have additional parentheses and must be complete with a from clause: `select count((select x from y)) from ...`

At last an advice: Use explicit join syntax (INNER JOIN x ON ..., LEFT JOIN y ON ..., etc.) instead of only listing tables with comma. That enhances readability and helps avoid errors.

Comment: Could you explain what is happening with the left join?

Comment: Yes. SELECT * from A LEFT JOIN B ON A.x = B.y. If there is a match for A.x then you join just like normal. If however there is no match for A.x then you get the A record joined with an empty B record (the B fields are NULL then, B.y is NULL then for instance).

Comment: I just notice that my select statement is not correct. I was (and still am) confused with id.complete and to_deliver. to_deliver belongs to table invoice_line? What do you count:(to_deliver,complete) => (1,1) = delivered, (0,1) = remaining, (\*,\*) = total? Or (1,\*) = total? Or (\*,1) = total?

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like the following:

```
declare @toDeliver as int = (SELECT COUNT(INVOICE_ID) FROM INVOICE_LINE AS I, INVOICE_COMPLETE      AS IC WHERE TO_DELIVER = 0 AND I.INVOICE_ID = IC.INVOICE_ID AND IC.COMPLETE = 1)
declare @deliverd as int = (SELECT COUNT(INVOICE_ID) FROM INVOICE_LINE AS I, INVOICE_COMPLETE AS    IC WHERE TO_DELIVER = 1 AND I.INVOICE_ID = IC.INVOICE_ID AND IC.COMPLETE = 1) 
SELECT 
    @toDeliver as REMAINING, 
    @delivered as DELIVERED,
    @toDeliver + @delivered AS TOTAL
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers give you better ideas on how to do this.

But the error seems to be coming from the subselects inside of the count function.

This change might work for you:

```
    SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(INVOICE_ID) FROM INVOICE_LINE AS I, INVOICE_COMPLETE AS IC WHERE TO_DELIVER = 1 AND I.INVOICE_ID = IC.INVOICE_ID AND IC.COMPLETE = 1) AS DELIVERED, 
    (SELECT COUNT(INVOICE_ID) FROM INVOICE_LINE AS I, INVOICE_COMPLETE AS IC WHERE TO_DELIVER = 0 AND I.INVOICE_ID = IC.INVOICE_ID AND IC.COMPLETE = 1) AS REMAINING,
    COUNT(INVOICE_ID) AS TOTAL
FROM INVOICE_LINE AS I, INVOICE_COMPLETE AS IC
WHERE TO_DELIVER = 1
AND I.INVOICE_ID = IC.INVOICE_ID
```

This simply moves the count inside the subselect.

Or add parenthesis around the subselects:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT((SELECT INVOICE_ID FROM INVOICE_LINE AS I, INVOICE_COMPLETE AS IC WHERE TO_DELIVER = 1 AND I.INVOICE_ID = IC.INVOICE_ID AND IC.COMPLETE = 1)) AS DELIVERED, 
    COUNT((SELECT INVOICE_ID FROM INVOICE_LINE AS I, INVOICE_COMPLETE AS IC WHERE TO_DELIVER = 0 AND I.INVOICE_ID = IC.INVOICE_ID AND IC.COMPLETE = 1)) AS REMAINING,
    COUNT(INVOICE_ID) AS TOTAL
FROM INVOICE_LINE AS I, INVOICE_COMPLETE AS IC
WHERE TO_DELIVER = 1
AND I.INVOICE_ID = IC.INVOICE_ID
;
```